# Underlying IWebBrowser com object in outlook folder

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I created a folder in outlook and set its homepage.

Is there's anyway of retrieving the folder's underlying web-browser com object? (or any other way which will allow me to interact with the document element)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any direct property or method for that. Try to use [Accesibility API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx).